# How can I run lein repl outside of a project?

Tags: clojure, leiningen, nrepl

I spent some time last night messing with my leinigen profiles.clj to get rid of all the errors that were being printed when starting cider in my project. Today I went to start a repl from the terminal (I like to keep one open while I work) but it didn't work. I thought it was a cider issue so I tried it from Emacs but even in Emacs if I'm not in a project the repl won't start.

Here's the error:

```
Error loading refactor-nrepl.middleware: clojure.lang.ArityException: Wrong number of args (4) passed to: StringReader, compiling:(abnf.clj:186:28)
Exception in thread "Thread-4" java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor in this context, compiling:(NO_SOURCE_PATH:0:0)
...
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resolve var: refactor-nrepl.middleware/wrap-refactor in this context
```

My ~/.lein/profiles.clj

```
{:user {:plugins [[lein-try "0.4.3"]
                  [refactor-nrepl "1.1.0"]
                  [cider/cider-nrepl "0.9.1"]]
        :dependencies [[org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
                       [acyclic/squiggly-clojure "0.1.4"]
                       ^:replace [org.clojure/tools.nrepl "0.2.12"]
                       [refactor-nrepl "1.1.0"]]}}
```

The versions of things when cider starts in a project

`; CIDER 0.9.1 (Java 1.8.0_45, Clojure 1.7.0, nREPL 0.2.12)`

I'm still pretty new to Clojure, Leinigen, Emacs, etc so I'm not sure why everything above made made my cider errors go away but it did. The cider errors I was getting were having to do with the nrepl version being too low and not having certain things installed (like refactor-nrepl).

Answer (score 0):

When starting a repl from lein using `lein repl`, it really wants to run in a lein project dir.  I keep an empty lein project named `clj` around in my home dir for this purpose. That way, my common dependencies are already there in the `project.clj` file, and lein is pre-configured just the way I like it.

You can start `lein repl` in an empty dir, but you get 10-20 error messages each time before it starts.

Another way is to use the plain repl built into the clojure jar file:

```
~/dummy > cp /home/alan/.m2/repository/org/clojure/clojure/1.8.0-RC1/clojure-1.8.0-RC1.jar .   
~/dummy > d *
-rw-rw-r-- 1 alan alan 3935726 Nov 19 14:11 clojure-1.8.0-RC1.jar
~/dummy > java -jar clojure-1.8.0-RC1.jar 
Clojure 1.8.0-RC1
user=>
```

As you can see, I created an empty directory named `dummy` and copied in the `clojure-*.jar` file. You can then run it with the syntax `java -jar xxx.jar` and it will fire up a repl completely independently of lein.

Comment: I know I can do an empty project, which is what I may end up doing. It's just head scratching that I used to be able to launch anywhere and now I cant.

Answer (score 0):

I also just keep a *scratch* project which I use for quick/simple repl sessions. There is a lien-oneoff plugin which is supposed to make it easy to work with simple single file lein projects which might be useful.

The other thing you could do is setup a boot config for basically getting a repl up to work with

Answer (score 0):

what is your lein version, I am use `2.5.3`, I can start `lein repl` anywhere.

```
Shell:~ >: lein repl
nREPL server started on port 52343 on host 127.0.0.1 - nrepl://127.0.0.1:52343
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.10
Clojure 1.7.0
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 1.8.0_60-b27
    Docs: (doc function-name-here)
          (find-doc "part-of-name-here")
  Source: (source function-name-here)
 Javadoc: (javadoc java-object-or-class-here)
    Exit: Control+D or (exit) or (quit)
 Results: Stored in vars *1, *2, *3, an exception in *e

user=> Bye for now!
Shell:~ >: lein version
Leiningen 2.5.3 on Java 1.8.0_60 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM

Shell:~ >: cat .lein/profiles.clj 
{:1.2 {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.2.0"]]}
 :1.3 {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.3.0"]]}
 :1.4 {:dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]]}

 :user {:plugins [[lein-immutant "2.0.0-alpha2"]
                  [lein-clojars "0.9.1"]
                  [lein-ancient "0.5.5"]
                  [lein-kibit "0.0.8"]
                  [lein-try "0.4.3"]
                  [venantius/ultra "0.2.0"]]
        :ultra {:color-scheme :solarized_dark}}}
```

Comment: lein repl (in a project) `nREPL server started on port 55164 on host 127.0.0.1 -    nrepl://127.0.0.1:55164
REPL-y 0.3.5, nREPL 0.2.12
Clojure 1.7.0`


lein -v 

`Leiningen 2.5.1 on Java 1.8.0_45 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM`